# MySQL query for finding the weight of the edges in a graph

Tags: mysql, join

Lets say we have the table SP(sid, pid) which shows student sid is involved in project pid.
Now I want a mysql query to select all the pairs of students who involved at least in one project, and the number of projects that they collaborate in.

For example:
input:
S1     P1 
S1     P2
S2     P1
S3     P1
S4     P1
S4      P2

Output:

S1   S2  1 
S1   S3  1 
**S1   S4  2** 

S2   S3  1 
S2   S4  1 
S3   S4  1

Comment: Is this homework? If yes, tag it as `[homework]`.

Comment: No it's not. research question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eric's answer might be a bit improved:

```
select
    sp1.sid as sid1,
    sp2.sid as sid2,
    count(*) as num
from
    sp as sp1
    inner join sp as sp2 on sp1.pid=sp2.pid and sp1.sid<sp2.sid
group by sp1.sid, sp2.sid
;
```

Use < instead of <> to avoid geting (1,4,2) AND (4,1,2)

Comment: You have an extra ) at the end of the query.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different way of doing it.

```
select sid, sid2, count(*) from (
select sp.sid, second_student.sid as sid2,sp.pid from sp
  join sp as second_student where sp.pid = second_student.pid and sp.sid < second_student.sid) as students
  group by sid, sid2;
```

Comment: Why the subquery? It's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Join the table to itself:

```
select
    s1.StudentId,
    s2.StudentId,
    Count(1) as ProjectCount
from
    StudentProjects s1
    inner join StudentProjects s2 on
        s1.ProjectId = s2.ProjectId
        and s1.StudentId <> s2.StudentId
group by s1.StudentId, s2.StudentId
```

Here the join condition is where the projects are the same, but the student is not him or herself. This will filter out any projects a student worked on by him or herself, however. If that's all right with you, then we're good. If not, then you'll need to use a `left join` in lieu of an `inner join`, but with the same join conditions.