# MySQL query to extract email neighborhood

Tags: mysql, email, graph

I have a MySQL table called personxmessage, extracted from emails.  It has three fields, id (primary key), MessageID, and PersonID.  For each message referenced by MessageID, there are two or more records, each with a PersonID for a person who was included in the email (i.e. in sender, sent to, or cc).

I want to query this table to get a link list showing all the people who were linked to a given PersonID=XXXX, and the links between them defined by being included on the emails that include XXXX, preferably including a weight on the links showing the number of occurrences.  Another way of saying this, in graph terminology, is I'm trying to get the [neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(graph_theory)) of XXXX. For example, for entries like

```
MID   PID
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     1
2     2
3     1
3     3
3     4
```

For PersonID 1 I would like to get link list

```
P1    P2    Count    
1     1     3 
1     2     2 
1     3     2 
1     4     1 
2     3     1
3     4     1
```

Is it possible to do this with some kind of self-join?  If so what query would I use?  I have done some simpler joins (for example to get the star-graph of XXXX and other PersonIDs that are with XXXX on emails) but this one is over my head.

Comment: Could you please describe the different tables structures and put an example of what you want to output with the query?

Comment: I will edit original entry to show (comments can't do table formatting, apprently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` do to something sort of like that.  It's not a table but a result set of the related pids per mid.

```
select mid, group_concat(distinct pid order by pid separator ', ') as related_ppl
  from personxmessage
 group by mid;
```

**result**

```
  mid   related_ppl
    1   1, 2, 3
    2   1, 2
    3   1, 3, 4
```

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
select p.pid as pid1, pp.pid as pid2, count(*) as cnt
  from personxmessagep
  left join personxmessagepp
    on p.mid = pp.mid
   and p.pid < pp.pid
 group by p.pid, pp.pid;
```

**result**

```
pid  pid2 cnt
1    2    2
1    3    2
1    4    1
2         1
2    3    1
3         1
3    4    1
4         1
```

Comment: That's a partial solution, but would take extra processing to get the link list.  In the related section this popped up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538608/mysql-query-for-finding-the-weight-of-the-edges-in-a-graph?rq=1 which is doing mostly what I want, but for reasons I don't understand it doesn't give the links between 1 & 4 or 3 & 4 in the desired output above.  (It also doesn't give 1 & 1 but I don't really need that.)

Comment: That does it (with some replacement of names): select p.PersonID as pid1, pp.PersonID as pid2, count(*) as cnt from messagexperson as p left join messagexperson as pp on p.MessageID = pp.MessageID  and p.PersonID < pp.PersonID  group by p.PersonID, pp.PersonID;  Thanks!